# How to direct B2C Federated user to Microsoft common login endpoint

Tags: angularjs, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C and have added sign in/sign up with custom templates and policies. I am using msal.js on the frontend.

When any user tries to login to our application, we have process to know if the domain is already federated with Microsoft B2C. Once we identify the user, we want to direct the user to Microsoft common login endpoint by passing the login_hint, so that they are forced to use work account and get the id_token.

I am trying to get the endpoint working (need to pass login_hint, don't know how)

```
directauthority ="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?"+ this.Config.signUpSignInPolicy;

clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.directauthority, 
    );
```

I got an error "endpoints_resolution_error:Endpoints cannot be resolved"

How can I resolve this?

Please suggest

Thanks,

Comment: Um... I'm afraid of that Azure AD B2C doesn't support this. First, the endpoint should be the endpoint of that sign-in or sign-up Policy. Like  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<mydomain>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_B2C_P1&client_id=c0c12173-e210-4ac3-b47f-c0167c824c33&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login`

Comment: Are you federating your Azure AD B2C tenant with an Azure AD (Enterprise) tenant and you are wanting to sign users in to the enterprise tenant?

Comment: yes, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the "domain_hint" and "login_hint" parameters to the Azure AD B2C request:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=<policy>&...&domain_hint=onmicrosoft.com&login_hint=me@contoso.com`

If you set the "domain_hint" parameter to the Azure AD technical profile's `<Domain />` value, then Azure AD B2C will redirect to the Azure AD endpoint without showing the sign-up or sign-in page to the end user.

To pass the "login_hint" parameter through from Azure AD B2C to the Azure AD endpoint:

1) Create a "loginHint" claim type:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="loginHint">
      <DisplayName>Login Hint</DisplayName>
      <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>
  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

2) Add the "loginHint" input claim to the Azure AD technical profile:

```xml
<ClaimsProviders>
  <ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>onmicrosoft.com</Domain>
    <DisplayName>Work Account</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="WorkProfile">
        <DisplayName>Work Profile</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
        <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
        <Metadata>
          ...
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
          ...
        </CryptographicKeys>
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loginHint" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          ...
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
          ...
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
</ClaimsProviders>
```

The "loginHint" input claim references a *claims resolver* that sets this input claim value to the "login_hint" parameter of the Azure AD B2C request.

Comment: domain_hint will work with social IDP's . how do we handle this for the different corporate users, where the domains would be different. In other words, how can I invoke "WorkProfile"  ClaimsProvider

Comment: After re-reading your original question, I've updated the above answer, with information about passing the login hint from your front-end app through Azure AD B2C to Azure AD.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett pls help me, it not work, pls view at test.dynatex.io